# What software can I use to animate my character in Unity3D?

Tags: animation, games, character-design

I am new in Game Development and I want to know what Softwares can help me to create Good animations for my 3rd Person Character.

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Welcome to GD.  At this time I have closed your question because it is off-topic here.  We do have a [blender stack](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) you might find helpful and if you need gaming we do have a [game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Autodesk](http://www.autodesk.com/), [Maya](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview) and [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) are the best for animation. Blender is free.

Comment: Welcome to GD!!  This may answer the OP's question but in the future do you mind adding links to software/hardware site recommendations, it adds a better level of quality to answers.  I have edited your answer to include the links. thanks!